# 'Payment.GenLedDet' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, error-handling, data-layer

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class PaymentDAL
    {

     public void InsertInGenLedDet(GenLedDet genLedDet)
        {
        }

}
```

My Class GenLedDet is present inside `Payment namespace`

This is my code snippet in the Data Layer and this code is being used . Don't know why this error is coming as i do have another function where no such error is showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot make a `public` function that takes a non-public class as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
private class GenLedDet {
```

use

```
public class GenLedDet {
```